# Style meteor account ui

Tags: user-interface, meteor, styles, account

I thought it should be simple but I cant understand how to implement useraccounts:semantic-ui to my Meteor app. I added the package, and then what? Can anyone give me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Have you also added the `sematic:ui` package?

Comment: I have the semantic:ui-css package.

Comment: It's not clear in your question: you can't access the `/sign-in` and `/sign-up` route? If so, have you installed `iron:router`?

Comment: Now I use accounts-ui and call the template with {{>loginButtons}}. I thought that the template could be styled with for example useraccounts:semantic-ui. None of the links at atmosphere are working to the documentation so I cant find any information. Anyway, yes I use iron:router. Are I missing something here, is it not possible to just include the template? I will check out the sign routs.

Comment: I have really a hard time to understand this. Is there no one who have implemented an other ui design (semantic) for meteor accounts. I found some information here - http://useraccounts.meteor.com/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brief overview on how to include the [`useraccounts:semantic-ui`](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/semantic-ui) package:

1. Install the respective packages: `meteor add semantic:ui-css useraccounts:semantic-ui accounts-password` (or any other account service).
2. Include the `atForm` template which is used to handle all sorts of user account operations, e.g. sign up, login: `{{> atForm}}`.
3. Include the `atNavButton` template which is used to display a sign up or login button: `{{> atNavButton}}` **(optional)**.

Please note: You can lock the `atForm` template to a particular state with the `state` argument, e.g. `{{> atForm state='signUp'}}`. You probably want to do this for creating different routes (`/signup` or `/login`).